# 2022 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

### The 2022 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase [Completed]
2. Primary phase [Skipped due to <10 nominees]
3. Election phase [[Completed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25232/2022-community-moderator-election-results)]

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the [official election page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/election) for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta - just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).