# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/election/4) on Code Golf has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: caird coinheringaahing]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/election/4) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5120353218068480).

Answer (score 25):

### Thank you all for the votes

I look forward to working for y'all as a moderator here, continuing my on-going efforts to keep the site clean! It is unfortunate that lyxal missed out, as I'm sure they would have been an excellent moderator. I hope you run for moderator at the next election.

I'm already getting started with handling flags, and I'm ready to keep going over the future. As with the other moderators, I welcome any feedback to my moderation efforts, and you can contact me either by raising a flag, pinging me in chat, or even leaving a comment under one of my posts.

Thank you!

Comment: Hooray! Welcome to the team!

Comment: Congrats to @caird! :3